# Can the F# type system do this?

Tags: f#

I have a lot of various types that have a common purpose, but little else in common. For the sake of explanation, they might as well be along the lines of:

```
type blah<'a> = Blah of 'a

type huha<'a> = Huha of 'a
```

I often need to repeat a large chunk of boilerplate that could go inside a function along the lines of:

```
let f (x:something<int>) (g:something<char> -> float) : float =
```

But that would require somehow enforcing that the two somethings in the type are the same. In other words, I would like to be able to call the function f as:

```
f (Blah 1) (fun (b:blah<float>) -> .... )
f (Huha 1) (fun (b:huha<float>) -> .... )
```

Obviously, a trivial solution is to create a discriminated union of all the types function f could possibly take, and make every g (i.e. f's second argument) check it got whatever type it expected. But that means having a massive type that causes the universe to recompile every time anything changes, and it's not like checking types at runtime helps a great deal either.

So, can someone please see a way of doing what I want in a typesafe way? Many thanks.

Comment: Since this is .net, you could use an interface -- but I don't know how common they are in F#.

Comment: Interfaces are implemented in F#, but I am not sure how that would help. So I make all my various types implement some particular interface. Now a copy of the code I want to write just once needs to go inside every type. And when I want to invoke that code, I need dynamic dispatch to get the right instance. But the implementations have to have the same type, so then I also need to make all the arguments behave in some common way. This seems to have all the evils of just using a discriminated union, and would also be more complex? Do I miss anything obvious please?

Comment: I didn't mean to implement the actual function at the interface, but something like `extract : I<a> -> a`. (this replacing the pattern matching). Then you could make `f` polymorphic, but constrain it to that interface and then extract the value that's relevant for that type: `f x g = g (extract x)`. And this has the advantage over union types, that it is automatically extensible (not necessary to change the existing type definition). I hope that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you cannot do this directly in F#.

But maybe operator overloading will help. You would have to implement `f` for every type, though. But maybe you can delegate to a common implementation.

A code example for operator overloading, ensuring the right types:

```
type T<'a> =
   | T of 'a
   static member (.+.) (l:T<int>, r:T<char> -> float) = 42.0

type U<'a> =
   | U of 'a
   static member (.+.) (l:U<int>, r:U<char> -> float) = 13.1


let ft (t:T<char>) = 42.0

let fu (t:U<char>) = 42.0

let t = T 42 .+. ft
let u = U 13 .+. fu

// does not compile:
let wrong = T 42 .+. fu
```